# IBM worklight MFP 8.0 - Direct Update Failure

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm facing an issue with Direct Update on the Android app with IBM MFP Worklight 8.0

The app is getting an update after web resources are deployed. But after the apk receives an update, and user clicks on it - "Direct Update Failure" is shown.

When I debug the apk, at this moment, "Error in success callbackid: WLApp77301234" is printed

Version details:

cordova-plugin-mfp - 8.0.2019091217

IBM MFP Operations Console - 8.0.0.00 - 20201015 -1343

Any help is appreciated

Comment: A likely cause is a corrupt web archive. If you inspect the callback and the error object, what more details do you see?

Comment: The web archive works fine for some users. But some users are facing the issue. Can you tell me the function which can give the error details. wl.client.connect gives CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS.

Comment: What could be the reason for a corrupt web archive? The wlapp has been generated the standard way from CLI.

Comment: Issue seems to be coming for IPv6 protocol. When internet is on IPv6, Direct Update is failing, there is failure connecting to MFP server. With IPv4 there seems to be no issues at all.